# Splitting a line in C/C++ using whitespace as delimiter

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

pseudocode:

```
    Attributes[] = Split line(' ')
```

How?

I have been doing this:

```
  char *pch;
  pch = strtok(line," ");
  while(pch!=NULL)
  {
      fputs ( pch, stdout ); 


  }
```

and getting a non-written, stuck, exit file. It's something wrong with this?
Well, the thing isn't even meeting my pseudocode requirement, but I'm confused about how to index tokens (as char arrays) to my array, I guess I should write a 2-dim array?

Comment: The solution is different depending on whether you're using C or C++.

Comment: How about some of the examples from the following: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Tokenizer.aspx They are very efficient and somewhat elegant. The String Toolkit Library makes complex string processing in C++ simple and easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not quite a dup - for C++ see and upvote the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string) by @Zunino.

Basic code below but to see the full glorious elegance of the answer you are going to have to click on it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    string sentence = "Something in the way she moves...";
    istringstream iss(sentence);
    copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss),
             istream_iterator<string>(),
             ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
}
```

This hinges on the fact that by default, `istream_iterator` treats whitespace as its separator.  The resulting tokens are written to `cout` on separate lines (per separator specified in constructor overload for [ostream_iterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6y7x31.aspx)).

Answer (score 8):

Use `strtok` with `" "` as your delimiter.

Comment: That's great for C, for C++ see related question in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method is `boost::split`:

```
std::vector<std::string> words;
boost::split(words, your_string, boost::is_space());
```